# SQL Query odd behavior: Never finishes when executing with two variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been troubleshooting a SQL Stored Procedure which keeps hanging and does not finish the execution. I simplify the problem to the two variables declared. The SQL Query shown below is a snippet of the Stored Procedure. Here are the test case scenarios I performed.

- Replaced @startver and @endver in the WHERE clause with 56 and it worked. The query completed in less than a second.
- Replaced the @endver with @starver in the WHERE clause and it worked. The query completed in less than a second.
- Replaced the @starver with @endver in the WHERE clause and it worked. The query completed in less than a second.

When the two variables are placed together it does not work. It keeps showing

> Executing query...

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? How can I fix this? I am unable to Debug this because the SQL instance is in AWS and I do not have a sysadmin account.

```
DECLARE @startver int = 56, @endver int = 56

SELECT 
    Z_Prodver.ProdverID ProdverID,
    Prod.ProdName,
    Z_Prodver.Releasedver,
    Z_DNameLen.Z_DName Z_DName,
    Z_DItemOffsets.Offset DItemOffset,
    Z_DNameLen.Offset DNameIndex,
    (Z_FormType.storagesize * M.ASize * DItem.ASize * 
        CASE DType.grouped
            WHEN 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 8
        END
    ) AllocationSize,
    H_NAME()
FROM
    Z_Prodver,
    Prod,
    DItem,
    DType,
    M,
    Z_DNameLen,
    Z_DItemOffsets,
    ProdPerM,
    Z_ProdSupport,
    Form,
    Z_FormType
WHERE
    DItem.ProdverID >= @startver
    AND DItem.ProdverID <= @endver
    AND DItem.DName = Z_DNameLen.DName
    AND DType.DTypeName = DItem.DTypeName
    AND DType.ProdverID = DItem.ProdverID
    AND M.MName = DItem.MName
    AND M.ProdverID = DItem.ProdverID
    AND M.MName = ProdPerM.MName
    AND M.ProdverID = ProdPerM.ProdverID
    AND ProdPerM.ProdverID = Z_Prodver.ProdverID
    AND Z_DItemOffsets.ProdverID = Z_Prodver.ProdverID
    AND Prod.ProdName = ProdperM.ProdName
    AND Z_DItemOffsets.DName = DItem.DName
    AND Form.FormName = DItem.FormName
    AND Z_FormType.FormTypeName = Form.FormTypeName
    AND Form.ProdverID = DItem.ProdverID
    AND Z_DItemOffsets.HostName = H_NAME()
    AND Z_ProdSupport.ProdverID = M.ProdverID
    AND Z_ProdSupport.ProdName= Prod.ProdName
    AND Z_ProdSupport.PCSupport = 1
```

Update: I am still getting the same error after I re-wrote the query with proper inner joins.

```
    DECLARE @startversion int = 56, @endversion int = 56

SELECT 
    PC_ProductVersion.ProductVersionID AS ProductVersionID,
    Product.ProductName,
    PC_ProductVersion.ReleasedVersion,
    PC_DataNameLengths.PC_DataName AS PC_DataName,
    PC_DataItemOffsets.Offset AS DataItemOffset,
    PC_DataNameLengths.Offset AS ataNameIndex,
    (PC_FormatType.storagesize * Module.ArraySize * DataItem.ArraySize * 
        CASE DataType.grouped
            WHEN 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 8
        END
    ) AllocationSize,
    HOST_NAME()
FROM DataItem 
INNER JOIN PC_DataNameLengths 
    ON DataItem.DataName = PC_DataNameLengths.DataName 
INNER JOIN DataType
    ON DataType.DataTypeName = DataItem.DataTypeName 
    AND DataType.ProductVersionID = DataItem.ProductVersionID
INNER JOIN Module
    ON Module.ModuleName = DataItem.ModuleName 
    AND Module.ProductVersionID = DataItem.ProductVersionID
INNER JOIN ProductPerModule
    ON  ProductPerModule.ProductVersionID = Module.ProductVersionID 
    AND ProductPerModule.ModuleName = Module.ModuleName
INNER JOIN PC_DataItemOffsets
    ON PC_DataItemOffsets.DataName = DataItem.DataName
    AND PC_DataItemOffsets.HostName = HOST_NAME()
INNER JOIN PC_ProductVersion
    ON PC_ProductVersion.ProductVersionID = PC_DataItemOffsets.ProductVersionID
    AND PC_ProductVersion.ProductVersionID = ProductPerModule.ProductVersionID 
INNER JOIN Product
    ON Product.ProductName = ProductperModule.ProductName
INNER JOIN Format
    ON Format.FormatName = DataItem.FormatName
    AND Format.ProductVersionID = DataItem.ProductVersionID
INNER JOIN PC_ProductSupport
    ON PC_ProductSupport.ProductVersionID = Module.ProductVersionID
    AND PC_ProductSupport.ProductName= Product.ProductName
    AND PC_ProductSupport.PCSupport = 1
INNER JOIN PC_FormatType
    ON PC_FormatType.FormatTypeName = Format.FormatTypeName

WHERE
    DataItem.ProductVersionID >= @startversion
    AND DataItem.ProductVersionID <= @endversion
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: (1) Fix your query to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  (2) Try the recompile option in the stored procedure.  The issue may be caching of the execution plan.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but you really should use ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Try using RECOMPILE on the sproc. The plan the sproc is trying to use might not be the most efficient.

Comment: 3 comments saying the same - in just a few seconds! (And I beat fast typing Gordon!)

Comment: 3 comments with the same hint within 6 seconds...

Comment: @jarlh And you beat me :-)

Comment: When you run into things like this, it's always best to try and grab an estimated plan and learn to read plans to see what is actually going on. It might have given you insight into why you were seeing this.

Comment: @everyone, I will re-write and update you on this. The query was written back in 2002. It didn't occur to me to re-write it, but you guys did! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
DItem.ProdverID >= @startver AND DItem.ProdverID <= @endver
```

When the `@startver` and `@endver` are the same, this means **all** `ProdverID`

An ugly work around for this query would be:

```
and 1 = case when @startver = @endver and DItem.ProdverID <> @startver 
        then 0 
      else 1 
      end
```

But the whole query needs a rewrite with proper joins, and using a workaround like above would benefit greatly from `option (recompile)` or conversion to using dynamic sql.

Reference:

- [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)
- [Dynamic Search Conditions - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)
- [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)
- [An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example - Aaron Bertand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)

Comment: This Stored Procedure was written back in 2002. I will re-write it and see how it goes. Thank you very much.